# Use a find hash in Rails 3.x?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there any non-deprectated option in Rails 3 where i can pass a data structure in to execute a query, rather than use the method chaining approach ?

Consider a hash representing a set of critieria for limiting a set of records (say, Documents)..

```
{
  :conditions => {
    :account_id => 2
  },
  :limit => 5,         # page size
  :offset => 5,        # (page-1) * page_size
  :sort => 'id DESC'
}
```

This may come from a URL such as:

```
/documents.js?page_size=5&page=2&sidx=id&sord=DESC&filter[account_id]=2
```

And I want to avoid any issues of order-importance in the translation of the hash to the sequential series of calls of methods:

```
# which is 'right', or better ? 
Document.offset(5).where(:account_id => 2).limit(5)
Document.where(:account_id => 2).limit(5).offset(5)
```

I'm concerned that the programmatic transformation of a set of query criteria inferred from HTTP parameters or JSON objects may be more complicated if I have to walk the hash and created chained method calls.

Answer (score 1):

You can use classic find method:

```
Document.all :conditions => { :account_id => 2 }, :limit => 5, :offset => 5, :order => "id desc"
```

Comment: `Is there any __non-deprectated__ option in Rails 3`

Comment: missed the non-deprectated ;) but there will be plugin in 3.2 and following that will support this methods, so if Dean wants passing hash I would go with this anyway

Comment: Do you know this allgeged plugins name or developer ? Link ?

Comment: this is source: http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface, and quote: "These deprecations will be effective in Rails’ 3.1 release ( NOT Rails 3 ) and will be fully removed in Rails 3.2, though there will be an official plugin to continue supporting them. Consider this an advance warning as it involves changing a lot of code."